# Tensor Product as L-Module(Properties)

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, lie-algebras, tensors

I was trying to visualise tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ as $L$-Module ($L$ is Lie Algebra) under the operation $x.(v \otimes w)= x.v \otimes w + v \otimes x.w $ where $x \in L$, $v \in V$ and $w \in W$.

I want to verify the property:
$x.(as+bt)= a(x.s)+b(x.t)$ where $s$ and $t$ lie in $ V \otimes W$ and $a,b \in F$ where $F$ is field.

Please help in this regard.

Comment: Where are you stuck? It seems to me that when writing it out explicitly, one might need a lot of indices, but each step follows from either a definition or a basic property of the objects at hand. Presuming of course the $L$-action on $V$ and $W$ is $F$-linear, and the tensor product is taken over $F$.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg in verifying the property I am stuck. I am also studying semi-simple Lie Algebras under my masters project. I see that you are also doing your doctoral work in this field. How can I reach to you? I have some doubts as well.

Comment: Look, just write out $s= \sum_i v_i \otimes w_i$ and $t=\sum_j v_j \otimes w_j$ and then manipulate the left hand side with obvious operations until you reach the right hand side. Where in there do you not get further? -- If you have specific questions, just ask them on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the same.  But if you can possibly provide your mail, it would be better.